# iOS Pushbots not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, pushbots

Today I published my first app to the iOS App Store (hooray!).

When I tested the app, push notifications worked perfectly fine (using [pushbots](https://pushbots.com)). But after downloading the app from the App Store, I did not receive any push notifications anymore.

I'm hoping someone here knows what might be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Please check you have signed your app with the correct distribution certificate and check that you produce the apns.p12 file for distribution, also check that the pushbots identifier match

Comment: Karlo, thanks for your reply.
I have checked all those things and they were set up correctly

Comment: Ok so, you cant receive push on new installs in app store but... the devices are actually being registered in pushbots server?

Comment: Correct.
Also, I did receive the notifications when running (testing) the app on my iPhone via xcode.

Comment: Can you please post your app delegate methods to manage pushes

Comment: It was too long to post here, so I put it in a pastie. http://pastie.org/private/7x5l4yujcevvyxqccyg

I'd really appreciate it if you could have a look!

Comment: @KarloA.López, have you been able to take a look at the code? I'd really appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: Yes I have, the thing is I dont see anything strange in code, why dont you start a fresh project and see if you have the same problem? Im pretty sure its a certificate or Pushbots ID related issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'd rather not start a fresh project, as that means having to wait another month for it to finally be released to the App Store.
What I will do, is 'redoing' the certificates etc.

Comment: @KarloA.López That unfortunately didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I am also having this issue however i am using Phonegap Build.